# docker runner cant clone git repo on kubernetes setup with drone.io

Tags: kubernetes, drone.io, gitea

I've setup a Drone Server on a self-hosted kubernetes cluster and tried to use the [recommanded drone docker-runner](https://github.com/drone/charts/tree/master/charts/drone-runner-docker).

It is linked with a Gitea server also self-hosted on the same cluster and setup an Oauth2 app

[image]

My drone runner seems to be ok:

drone/drone-runner-docker-7796b4bbc6-gs6gd

```
level=info msg="starting the server" addr=":3000"
level=info msg="successfully pinged the remote server"
level=info msg="polling the remote server" arch=amd64 capacity=2 endpoint="https://drone.xxx.yyy" kind=pipeline os=linux type=docker
```

[image]

When i trigger a building job, it fails at the clone step:

[image]

Why is my runner not able to clone the repo despite i've setup the Oauth2 app etc ?

Was expecting the runner to clone the repo :p !